# Laravel Eloquent Model many-to-many or one-to-many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm a little bit confused after reading `Laravel` `Eloquent` Model documentation. So I have this database structure:

```
task
   id
   name
   description

tag
   id
   name

task_tag
   id
   task_id
   tag_id
```

One task may has zero, one or many tags. Of course one tag may has connection to zero, one or many tasks.

I tried this, but not sure:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model {
    public function tags() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

`hasMany()` is the best solution in this case or I need to use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like a typical many-to-many relationship (including the pivot table you've outlined). `hasMany()` is intended to be used in One To Many relationships. For Many To Many, you should use `belongsToMany()`. So your Task model would look like:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

[Relevant docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).